# Can I remove <h2></h2><br> if no text in <h2></h2>?

Tags: php, html, css, nivo-slider

This is the php code I am modifying to have a header and a description text box appear above the slider. It works great if there is a header and description set within the slider, but on other pages I just want the image - instead an empty "text box" is displayed as it reads the `<h2>` and `<br>` tags.

Is there anyway I can make an if .$item['itemImageTitle'] & .$item['itemTitle'] empty show just the image, if not empty show the boxes too?

css

```
.nivo-caption h2 {
font-size: xx-large;
color: #fff;
}

.theme-default .nivo-caption {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* z-index: 20; */
    -moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 23px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background: rgba(58, 88, 129, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  width: 95%;
  z-index: 8;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=1);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

php

```
<div class="slider-wrapper <?php  echo "theme-".$theme_title;?>" id="<?php  echo "slider-wrapper-".$bID; ?>">
    <div id="<?php  echo "nivo-slider-".$bID; ?>" class="nivoSlider" style="width: 100% !important;">
    <?php   
    foreach($items as $item) { 
        echo (strlen($item['itemUrl'])>1) ? '<a href="'.$item['itemUrl'].'">' : '';
        echo '<img src="'.$item['itemImageSrc'].'" alt="'.$item['itemImageAlt'].'" title="<h2>'.$item['itemTitle'].'</h2><br>'.$item['itemImageTitle'].'" data-thumb="'.$item['itemImageSrc'].'" >';
        echo (strlen($item['itemUrl'])>1) ? '</a>' : '';
    } 
    ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you just check if the `$item['itemTitle']` is null or empty?

Comment: Can you really put HTML markup in the title attribute? I have never seen this before... Is it valid?

Comment: why do you have H2 inside H2?

Comment: not sure if it's valid or good form but it works as intended. I know there will be better ways though but i'm new to php and it's nuances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said `if .$item['itemImageTitle'] & .$item['itemTitle'] empty show just the image`. You can try this

```
<div class="slider-wrapper <?php  echo "theme-".$theme_title;?>" id="<?php  echo "slider-wrapper-".$bID; ?>">
    <div id="<?php  echo "nivo-slider-".$bID; ?>" class="nivoSlider" style="width: 100% !important;">
    <?php   
    foreach($items as $item) { 
        echo (strlen($item['itemUrl'])>1) ? '<a href="'.$item['itemUrl'].'">' : '';

        $my_title = "";
        if(!empty($item['itemImageTitle']) && !empty($item['itemTitle'])){
           $my_title = '<h2>'.$item['itemTitle'].'</h2><br>'.$item['itemImageTitle'].'</h2>';

        }


        echo '<img src="'.$item['itemImageSrc'].'" alt="'.$item['itemImageAlt'].'" title="'.$my_title.'" data-thumb="'.$item['itemImageSrc'].'" >';
        echo (strlen($item['itemUrl'])>1) ? '</a>' : '';
    } 
    ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Here the logic is wrong 
` if(!empty($item['itemImageTitle']) && !empty($item['itemTitle'])){ `

use 

`  if(!empty($item['itemImageTitle']) || !empty($item['itemTitle'])){ `

Comment: @Vinay see what OP asked to do ... he mentioned `&&` so thats why I wrote that

Comment: Bro ! when their is 2 Not Joins .. then inplace of && we use ||

Comment: You are amazing, thankyou! Works perfectly, exactly what I had in mind.